# find fx forward rate from AUD FX_RFR and SORA_FX

Tags: fx, forward-rate

I am trying to derive AUDSGD forward rate. I have curves like AUD fx rfr curve which is comprised on the AUDOIS rates till 1year and AUD-USD rates based on the basis for 1year+. Similarly for SGD. Could someone help me to understand how to derive the forward rates, lets say for 5years.

thanks

Comment: You cannot wthout a lot of assumptions.  The 1 year rate need not have much in common with a 5 year rate. The link below solves for rates, but you can simply rearrange to solve for FWDs.